# How to use sha512 binary string function in RDS aurora PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am using AWS RDS Aurora PostgreSql engine version  11.9.
I have a requirement where I need to apply sha512 to one of the columns in the table. I can see that this binary string function is available in PostgreSql as per their documentation but could not find that in my Aurora PostgreSql.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-binarystring.html

Any leads on how to achieve sha512 in aurora PostgreSql or the version of aurora PostgreSql which supports this would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Extensions.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Extensions.11), Amazon Aurora has a pgcrypto extension. If that works like PostgreSQL, you can use the [`digest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.34.5.2) function to calculate a SHA512 hash:

```
SELECT digest('hello', 'sha512');
                                                               digest                                                               
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 \x9b71d224bd62f3785d96d46ad3ea3d73319bfbc2890caadae2dff72519673ca72323c3d99ba5c11d7c7acc6e14b8c5da0c4663475c2e5c3adef46f73bcdec043
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I cannot run the digest() function as well. 
Getting the below error when I run the sql: select encode(digest(<column_name>), 'sha512') 
from <table_name>

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function digest(unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 15

Comment: Forgot to run the create extension pgcrypto; command.
I can use digest now.
Thanks for the help

Comment: The function takes two arguments, see my example.